# count objects created in django application in past X days, for each day

Tags: python, date, python-2.7, types

I have following unsorted dict (dates are keys):

> {"23-09-2014": 0, "11-10-2014": 0, "30-09-2014": 0, "26-09-2014": 0,
>   "03-10-2014": 0, "19-10-2014": 0, "15-10-2014": 0, "22-09-2014": 0,
>   "17-10-2014": 0, "29-09-2014": 0, "13-10-2014": 0, "16-10-2014": 0,
>   "12-10-2014": 0, "25-09-2014": 0, "14-10-2014": 0, "08-10-2014": 0,
>   "02-10-2014": 0, "09-10-2014": 0, "18-10-2014": 0, "24-09-2014": 0,
>   "28-09-2014": 0, "10-10-2014": 0, "21-10-2014": 0, "20-10-2014": 0,
>   "06-10-2014": 0, "04-10-2014": 0, "27-09-2014": 0, "05-10-2014": 0,
>   "01-10-2014": 0, "07-10-2014": 0}

I am trying to sort it from oldest to newest.
I've tried code:

```
mydict = OrderedDict(sorted(mydict .items(), key=lambda t: t[0], reverse=True))
```

to sort it, and it *almost* worked. It produced sorted dict, but it has ignored months:

> {"01-10-2014": 0, "02-10-2014": 0, "03-10-2014": 0, "04-10-2014": 0,
>   "05-10-2014": 0, "06-10-2014": 0, "07-10-2014": 0, "08-10-2014": 0,
>   "09-10-2014": 0, "10-10-2014": 0, "11-10-2014": 0, "12-10-2014": 0,
>   "13-10-2014": 0, "14-10-2014": 0, "15-10-2014": 0, "16-10-2014": 0,
>   "17-10-2014": 0, "18-10-2014": 0, "19-10-2014": 0, "20-10-2014": 0,
>   "21-10-2014": 0, "22-09-2014": 0, "23-09-2014": 0, "24-09-2014": 0,
>   "25-09-2014": 0, "26-09-2014": 0, "27-09-2014": 0, "28-09-2014": 0,
>   "29-09-2014": 0, "30-09-2014": 0}

How can I fix this?

EDIT:
I need this to count objects created in django application in past X days, for each day.

```
event_chart = {}
date_list = [datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 30)]
for date in date_list:
    event_chart[formats.date_format(date, "SHORT_DATE_FORMAT")] = Event.objects.filter(project=project_name, created=date).count()

event_chart = OrderedDict(sorted(event_chart.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(event_chart))
```

Comment: You need to convert those strings to `datetime` objects to make them sort correctly - have a look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html). Alternatively, if you can change format to `'yyyy-mm-dd'` they will sort correctly as strings.

Comment: The problem is, I am already converting these dates from datetime objects. And each of them should localised. Please check my edit

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `datetime` module to parse the strings into actual dates:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> sorted(mydict .items(), key=lambda t:datetime.strptime(t[0], '%d-%m-%Y'), reverse=True)
```

Comment: I am using django, and each date should be localised. Please check my edit

Comment: Well, even better - there you already have `date` items - in order, even. Why do you destroy the order, only to re-sort in that order afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a json response in the format: `{"22-09-2014": 0, 23-09-2014": 0, "localized date": count_for_that_date}` so that oldest dates will appear earlier in the output then you could make `event_chart` an `OrderedDict`:

```
event_chart = OrderedDict()
today = DT.date.today() # use DT.datetime.combine(date, DT.time()) if needed
for day in range(29, -1, -1): # last 30 days
    date = today - DT.timedelta(days=day)
    localized_date = formats.date_format(date, "SHORT_DATE_FORMAT")
    day_count = Event.objects.filter(project=name, created=date).count()
    event_chart[localized_date] = day_count
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(event_chart))
```